# Find max values within Column 1 range and print column2

Tags: awk, numeric-data

I have a representative dataset

```
 35.5259  327   
 35.526  326   
 35.526  325  
 35.5261  324   
 35.5262  323   
 35.5263  322   
 35.5264  321   
 35.5265  320   
 35.5266  319  
 35.5268  318


# Contour 4, label:
 35.5269  317   
 35.527  316  
 35.5272  315  
 35.5274  314   
 35.5276  313   
 35.5278  312   
 35.528  311  

# Contour 4, label:
 35.5282  310  
 35.5285  309  
 35.5287  308  
 35.529  307  
 35.5293  306
```

I try to find the two max values within a range in col 2 with:

```
awk '320>$2,$2>315 && $1>max1{max1=$1;line=$2} 313>$2,$2>307 && $1>max2{max2=$1;line2=$2} END {printf " %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\n",max1,line,max2,line2}' FILENAME
```

I just get blank ouput (As I have lots of blank spaces in the txt file)How to ignore that ? with $1+0 == $1 ?

I would like to find the Max values in col1 between 320 and 315 and between 313-307 in col2. The output I need:

```
35.5266  319   35.5278  312
```

How do I get the desired output ?
Thanks

Comment: Could you tell us what the range is that you're interested in, and include data that are representative of your actual data ("has lots of blank spaces")?

Comment: @Kusalananda I have edited the ques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works well if you change `,` to `&&`.

But I think you have a logical error, too. Shouldn't `$1>max1` rather be`$2>line1` (and the same for `max2/line2`) ?

```
awk '
  320>$2 && $2>315 && $2>line1 {max1=$1;line1=$2}
  313>$2 && $2>307 && $2>line2 {max2=$1;line2=$2}
  END {printf " %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\n",max1,line1,max2,line2}
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that pLumo's answer does indeed give your sample output, but your question is about finding maximum values *within column 1 range*; the example output is printing the maximum value *in column 2*. So I think you've either mis-stated your question or your sample output. Also when you say "between" 320 and 315 are those numbers themselves included? I'll assume they are in this proposed solution (so `>=` operator); I'm using `next` to ignore any lines that don't have just 2 fields; I initialise my chosen variables with a `BEGIN` by way of good practice.

```
awk 'BEGIN {max1=max2=line1=line2=0}
     NF!=2 {next}
     320>=$2 && $2>=315 && $1>max1 {max1=$1;line1=$2}
     313>=$2 && $2>=307 && $1>max2 {max2=$1;line2=$2}
     END {printf " %s\t %s\t %s\t %s\n",max1,line1,max2,line2}' file.name.here
```

Comment: you don't need to skip these lines as they will get skipped automatically due to `$2>=315`  being false if `$2` is unset.